# What are the limits of gyroscopes in producing momentum?

Tags: angular-momentum, gyroscopes

I was reading a little bit about how gyroscopes can be used to store and release angular momentum, and that got me thinking about a device from the recent William Gibson novel [The Peripheral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Peripheral).

In the book there is a futuristic weapon in the form of a big cube.  The cube can spin on a single point with very high rotational speed, but also launch itself from the ground to smash into walls and objects, in a way that seems to be angular, with lethal momentum.

Gibson is an author that confines himself to speculation based on valid hypotheses and the question of how such a device might work has been bugging me for a while.

I suppose the alloy used for the exterior and structure of the cube could be flexible, allowing warping to increase momentum on the snap back, but what is the underlying principle to create such momentum?

Also, could gyroscopes be used to make a self contained object appear to levitate, as opposed to merely spring?

Answer (score 2):

The limit of any manmade gyroscope in producing angular momentum is based on the material of which it is made, (without straying into science fiction exotic materials.)

Once you start to spin it up, the angular momentum will increase until the molecular bonds of the disc itself are unable to maintain the crystalline structure, and the disc will break apart.

In essence, this is no different than tying a stone to a string and spinning it around until the string breaks. A stronger string will delay this  breakage but it will happen again at a higher angular velocity.

> In the book there is a futuristic weapon in the form of a big cube. The cube can spin on a single point with very high rotational speed, but also launch itself from the ground to smash into walls and objects, in a way that seems to be angular, with lethal momentum.

The [South American Bolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolas), used as a weapon, or to catch animals,  has been around for a long time, and it  can be made to rotate at high  speed, but when you let it go, it travels in a direction parallel to the ground. There is some other force needed to "jump" upwards.

> I suppose the alloy used for the exterior and structure of the cube could be flexible, allowing warping to increase momentum on the snap back, but what is the underlying principle to create such momentum?

I am not sure of your point here, but I think you might be expecting linear momentum to be converted to angular momentum. I don't know how this could occur.

> Also, could gyroscopes be used to make a self contained object appear to levitate, as opposed to merely spring?

No, appearing to float is a trick or an optical illusion. Actually achieving levitation is not possible for a standard gyroscope.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  In the proposed system (the cube) all mechanisms are internal, which is why I speculated on the frame as a way of using resistance to create momentum.

Comment: No problem, I have most of his books but I don't remember the cube. If you want to see what happens when angular momentum exceeded material strength, Google Steam engine governer failure or similar. With a heavy flywheel, it was not unusual for the mill walls to be demolished.

Comment: @DukeZhou Note that, at an abstract level, the rail gun with its extremely high momentum / kinetic energy shells is a similar idea to the weapon you speak of: objects containing extremely high linear or angular momentum can be as destructive as lower momentum explosive shells.